# Error: "User.email"'s Type is invalid! Type is: "undefined" [E009]

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, babeljs, typegoose

I get this error after i transpiled my typescript to javascript and using typegoose for my model, dont know the fix, anybody here?

```
at getModelForClass (/Users/user/Documents//node_modules/@typegoose/typegoose/src/typegoose.ts:89:58)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents//dist/model/user.model.js:193:49)
```

Comment: can you please show us the model file?

Comment: please provide your class (or at least the field with decorators), also make sure you have all [Requirements](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide#requirements) and read [Error & Warning Details: E009](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/error-warning-details#invalid-type-e009)

Answer (score 3):

In your tsconfig file uncomment this line:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */,
```

Comment: Why exactly? It will suppress this error and not fix the problem